# Typo3 onepage include subpages with their own templates

Tags: typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I have Typo3-Website with a onepage-layout. This Website has several sections (news, portfolio, Slideshow, ... ). Every section has its own specific layout/template. In Typo3 I have this sections as subpages with their own templates. The following code from a tutorial gives me the content of this subpages in the correct order.

```
lib.sectionContent {
  1 = TMENU
  1 {
    NO = 1
    NO {
      doNotLinkIt = 1
      stdWrap >
      stdWrap {
        cObject = COA
        cObject {
          if.value = 5
          if.equals.field = doktype
          if.negate = 1
          10 < temp.titleSectionId
          10.wrap = <section id="|" class="page-section" style="margin-top: 30px;">
          20 = CONTENT
          20 {
            table = tt_content
            select {
              pidInList.field = uid
            }
            renderObj < tt_content
          }
          30 = TEXT
          30 {
            wrap = </section>
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I need the used template too. I need a way to integrate the subpages with their templates into the parent-page/onepage-website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to render the template with the content of that page instead of only the content.

so your 20 should be a template object like this:

```
20 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
20 {
    file.cObject = CASE
    file.cObject {
        key.field = backend_layout

        1 = TEXT
        1.value = fileadmin/templates/first.html

        default = TEXT
        default.value = fileadmin/templates/default.html
    }

    variables {
        content < styles.content.get
        content.select.pidInList.field = uid
    }
}
```

be aware to respect also `backend_layout_next_level` and other than the main column. also prefer template folders (...RootPaths) than immediate filename.

Comment: Adding a ".value" to the second "default" i've got the templates I've looked for. Thank you for that. But there is still no content. I'm using <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.content" data="{colPos: 0}" /> in the template. Any suggestions?

Comment: oops. I added the missing `.value`. the problem with the f:cObject might be that you might miss some context. e.g. you might miss the page-uid. my example could only work because we are in the context of a TMENU.1 so we could access fields of the page currently handled in the menu.